# How make words change after reload pages

Tags: php, html, css, reload, words

I want make words change after user reload the website

[image: Like this website here]

[image: Like this website here]

[image: Like this website here]

Comment: you'll need an array of words and a random 'generator' like `rand()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side word's generator isn't the best idea. Use instead client-side.
You can use server to get list of words or any other source of them.
Below two samples for your project:

- first one based on array of words as a source
- second one based on string

```js
// 1. Array
var words = ['One', 'Morning', 'Star'];

// 2. String
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum euismod nisl a malesuada laoreet. Vivamus consequat, mi vel fermentum ultricies, dui libero ullamcorper velit, eu hendrerit lacus lorem a lacus. Suspendisse id diam quam. In tristique risus non turpis feugiat sagittis. Nam vitae turpis tincidunt leo faucibus ultrices. Suspendisse tristique pharetra ante, sit amet luctus odio. Pellentesque libero tortor, lacinia in mattis ut, ullamcorper a enim. Donec gravida, neque eget lacinia porta, quam ex rhoncus sem, ac semper ligula lacus non ligula. Vivamus id risus convallis, rhoncus nisi et, efficitur magna. In sit amet dolor ut dui accumsan dignissim. Curabitur lobortis nisi eu sapien accumsan luctus. Nullam blandit turpis ut massa ultricies cursus.";

var wordFromArr = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var wordFromString = text.split(" ")[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

document.getElementById("output").innerText = wordFromArr;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: code working in simulator but in my website its showing number

Comment: @EsmailELBoB You've done something wrong. Give me result

Comment: actually its worked xD (its code from net but yeah its worked) + i not have logs.txt in my website hoster

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = ["Bonjourr", "Holaa", "Hi! Mister", "Hello World", "Nice!"];
$word_count  = count($words);
$selected_number = rand(0, ($word_count-1)); 
$selected_word = $words[$selected_number];
echo "{$selected_word}";
```

Let's try this

Comment: What is the output

Comment: actually its worked xD (its code from net but yeah its worked) + i not have logs.txt in my website hoster